# Laravel 5.4 If statement doesn't work in __construct()

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, paradox, construct

Basically this is my __construct of my controller. When non-logged user try go access routes in this controller he is basically redirected to **login** route. So far so good - if condition is working, redirect is working, route is working.

So next I try to check if users access token is valid and if it's not I will redirect him to **logout** route - to simplify my example I don't do this but instead I check if $test_var is equal to 1 and redirect to **login** as we already know this route name as working.

Neither first **if($test_var == 1)**, not second **if($test_var == 1)** trigger - there's no redirect or die.

I even tried **if(1==1)** ..

I even tried to:

```
 if(isset($this->userCredentials))
         return redirect('login');
```

and it still doesn't trigger. It's really strange as if I'm not logged first **if(!isset...** is working and redirects, but this piece of code is doing nothing if I'm logged in:

Looks like the **If** is the problem, but this If beyond quantum theory obviosly..

This is the full code of the construct:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Input; 
use Session;
use Auth;
use Redirect;

class stackoverflowController extends ConnectionController
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');


    $this->userCredentials = Session::get('userCredentials');


    if(!isset($this->userCredentials))
        return redirect('login');

    $test_var = 1;

    if($test_var == 1)
        return redirect('login');

    if($test_var == 1)
        die(1);

    if(1 == 1)
        die(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, If statment works, problem will be in redirect. At least in L4.2 i had same problem, only redirect dont worked.

In laravel 4.2 works send(), but I didnt use it in L5 yet, so pleasy try if it works:

```
return redirect('login')->send();
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked out this way. I still can't explain my self why somewhere redirect works without send().

Comment: Problem is, that the redirect is called in constructor. And it is somehow rewriting redirect action.

Comment: @АтанасАтанасов Remember that any value you return from constructor is ignored. This works only because `send` method probably exits the script after sending the redirect header.

Comment: Thank you for the further explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Your session isn't be loaded. Edit your Controller `__construct` to

```
$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
  $this->userCredentials = Session::get('userCredentials');

  if(!isset($this->userCredentials))
    return redirect('login');

  $test_var = 1;

  if($test_var == 1)
    return redirect('login');

  if($test_var == 1)
    die(1);

  if(1 == 1)
    die(1);

  return $next($request);
});
```

or change your app\Http\Kernel.php to

```
protected $middleware = [
  ...
  \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
];
```

Answer (score -1):

Name your login route as `login` then try this:

redirect()->route('login');

Comment: The problem is not the redirect as If user is not logged in, it redirects. But if user is logged in, next If doesn't work. Like they are not there at all.

Comment: what different between accepted anwser and my answer? @АтанасАтанасов